# c++ Ошибка при создании сокета

Tags: c++, сокет, winsock

```
#pragma comment( lib, "wsock32.lib" )
#include <winsock2.h>

    int main()
    {
        int handle = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
        cout << handle << endl;
        if ( handle <= 0 )
        {
            printf( "failed to create socket\n" );
            return false;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Пытаюсь создать сокет по уроку через socket(), но она возвращает -1. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup

Comment: @Croessmah, спасибо, помогло

Comment: В windows дескриптор сокета, не инт, а SOCKET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переношу в ответы комментарий Croessmath.

Чтобы можно было работать с сокетами - сначала нужно инициализировать соответствующую подсистему. Это делается с помощью вызова функции
[`WSAStartup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup), которой передать запрос необходимой для работы версии WinSock:

```
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;

    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        /* Сообщение, что все плохо и Winsock DLL не найдена. */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Проверка, что WinSock DLL поддерживает версию 2.2.*/

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        /* Сообщение, что все плохо и Winsock DLL не найдена. */
        printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");
```